# Robot Framework : how to connect to Oracle database

Tags: python, oracle, robotframework

We are trying our luck with robot framework for tests. Automation. I am stuck at database connection at this point.

A DB connection using cx_Oracle is displaying an error saying “ No keyword withy the name  cx_Oracle’ . If you have any idea please help . It will be helpful if you could put out an example of the Oracle dB connection sample.

Comment: You need to have an Oracle connection library installed - [cx_Oracle](https://oracle.github.io/python-cx_Oracle/). Its install instructions are straightforward; after it's in, connecting/querying is trivial - follow the examples of the DatabaseLibrary.

Comment: Thank you .I have installed the cx_orcle connection library. When tried use it I have getting the keyword not found issue. I checked and I am writing it with proper intends n all. Using PyCharm for IDE.

Comment: Check that the library is installed in the python environment your Robotframework uses - you might have installed it in the system's python and using RF in virtualenv, or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Check **DatabaseLibrary** available with RobotFramework.

[Check Here for more info !!!](http://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/)

[DatabaseLibrary Keyword Documentation](http://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/api/1.0.1/DatabaseLibrary.html)

It has two keywords for Database Connection :

1. Connect To Database
2. Connect To Database Using Custom Params

Comment: I think OP is beyond discovering DatabaseLibrary, the issue at hand is having an Oracle driver running for it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and This is the solution which I found

Step 1: Install Oracle instant client (32 bit) ( I'm using instantclient_18_3, You don't have to install cx_oracle seperately )

Step 2: Install Operating System Literary and the Database Library for Robot and import it

```
*** Settings ***
Library           DatabaseLibrary
Library           OperatingSystem
```

Then in your robot script, Add The following variable and make sure it's with the test cases (NOT in an external resource file)

```
*** Variables ***
${DB_CONNECT_STRING}    'DB_USERNAME/DB_PASSWORD@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=YOUR_DB_OR_HOST)(PORT=YOUR_PORT))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=YOUR_SID)))'
```

Then you can use the following keywords to set the environment variables and to run queries

```
*** Keywords ***
Connect To DB
    [Arguments]    ${DB_CONNECT_STRING_VALUE}
    Set Environment Variable    PATH    PATH_TO_YOUR_INSTANT_CLIENT\\instantclient_18_3
    Set Global Variable    ${DB_CONNECT_STRING_VALUE}
    #Connect to DB
    connect to database using custom params    cx_Oracle    ${DB_CONNECT_STRING_VALUE}

Run Query and log results
    [Arguments]    ${QUERY_TO_EXECUTE}
    Set Global Variable    ${QUERY_TO_EXECUTE}
    ${queryResults}    Query    ${QUERY_TO_EXECUTE}
    log to console    ${queryResults}

Disconnect From DB
    #Disconnect from DB
    disconnect from database
```

Finally, in your test case run it like this

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test Connetion
    [Tags]    DBConnect
    Connect To DB    ${DB_CONNECT_STRING}
    Run Query and log results    SELECT sysdate from Dual
```

This should work fine for you

Answer (score 0):

"No keyword withy the name cx_Oracle" means that you are using 'cx_Oracle' as keyword.
I do not see given library in commonly used [Robot Extended libraries](http://robotframework.org/#libraries).
If the case is that you installed the library wrongly and imported it correctly into Robot script as:

```
*** Settings ***
Library   MyLibraryName
```

then I would expect it to fail on the import.

I agree with Dinesh. Try to use the Database Library first.

Or if you cannot use Database Library (the *Connect To Database Using Custom Params* has limitations), it is possible to write your own Robot Library that would reuse the cx_Oracle python library and expose keywords to robot. It is generally [not that complicated](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-libraries) and I did that with pyodbc.

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed an installation issue. We had to use Anaconda3 and had to installed the library under its site-packages . I had this one under default Python folder.The issue is now resolved .

Answer (score 0):

You can use [robotframework-oracledb-library](https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-oracledb-library/)

- Install OracleDBLibrary module

  ```
  pip install robotframework-oracledb-library
  ```
- After the installation, you can import OracleDBLibrary and connect to Oracle Database as follows

  ```
  *** Settings ***
  Library           OracleDBLibrary

  *** Variables ***
  ${HOST}      localhost
  ${PORT}      1521
  ${SID}       ORCLCDB
  ${USER}      SYS
  ${PASSWORD}  Oradoc_db1
  ${MODE}      SYSDBA

  *** Test Cases ***
  CONNECT TO ORACLE DATABASE WITH SID SUCCESSFULLY
      ${DSN} =  ORACLE MAKEDSN  host=${HOST}  port=${PORT}  sid=${SID}
      ORACLE CONNECT  user=${USER}  
      ...             password=${PASSWORD} 
      ...             dsn=${DSN} 
      ...             mode=${MODE}
      ${CONNECTION STATUS} =  ORACLE CONNECTION PING
      SHOULD BE EQUAL  ${CONNECTION STATUS}  ${NONE}
      ORACLE CONNECTION CLOSE
  ```

For more information, you can check [robotframework-oracledb-library-test](https://github.com/adeliogullari/robotframework-oracledb-library/blob/main/test/OracleDatabase.robot)